# How to retrieve data to display in drop down list based on another selected value from another drop down list MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an `mvc 4` application using entity framework code first in my data base i have three table Products and Category and `SubCategory` where the Products table contain information about the product and the Category contain Category like Man - Woman - Kids and the `SubCategory` contain `SubCategory` like Shoes - Dresses - Suit where each Sub Category belong to one Category or more like the Sub Category Suits belong only for the Man Category an the Shoes belong to all  Categories Man - Woman - Kids [image]

and the classes i used to build this data base is

1.Products Classe:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "ProductID,Discount")]
public class Product
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string ProductImageURL { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int Sales { get; set; }

    public decimal Discount { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string SubCategory { get; set; }

    public int ColorID { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public int SizeID { get; set; }
    public Size Size { get; set; }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

2.Category Class:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "CategoryID")]
public class Category
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategorys { get; set; }
}
```

3.Sub-Category Class:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "SubCategoryID")]
public class SubCategory
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }

    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

so to create product i use this logic to do that in the product Controller in the action method create:

```
    // GET: /Products/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categorys, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
        ViewBag.SubCategoryID = new SelectList(db.SubCategorys, "SubCategoryID", "SubCategoryName");
        ViewBag.ColorID = new SelectList(db.Colors, "ColorID", "ColorName");
        ViewBag.SizeID = new SelectList(db.Sizes, "SizeID", "SizeName");
        ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companyies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
        return View();
    }

 // POST: /Products/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categorys, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", product.CategoryID);
        ViewBag.SubCategoryID = new SelectList(db.SubCategorys, "SubCategoryID", "SubCategoryName");
        ViewBag.ColorID = new SelectList(db.Colors, "ColorID", "ColorName", product.ColorID);
        ViewBag.SizeID = new SelectList(db.Sizes, "SizeID", "SizeName", product.SizeID);
        ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companyies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName", product.CompanyID);
        return View(product);
    }
```

and in the create View:

```
@model StopeAndShop.Models.Product

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<legend>Product</legend>
<div class="container">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductImageURL)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductImageURL)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductImageURL)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sales)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sales)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sales)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Discount)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Discount)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Discount)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCategory)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("SubCategoryID", string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCategory)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ColorID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ColorID", string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ColorID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SizeID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("SizeID", string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SizeID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyID)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</div>
}

<div>
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

  @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

so my question is how to retrieve only the correspond `SubCategory` to the selected Category. 
becase in my logic it retrieve all the `SubCategory` in the drop down list ignoring the selected Category and i'm beginner in the `mvc` so is this the correct way to do this bring the data via view bags an send it to the view or there is anther proper way or preferred
it look like that:

[image]

and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In Your SubCategory Table give category id.
Let say category table as:

```
CatId CatName
  1    Men
  2    Women
```

Subcategory table as:

```
SubCatId SubCatName CatId
  1        Suit      1
  2       dresses    2
```

You will get relevant data in dropdown.

Comment: that what i did but how can i retrieve the Subcategory that only belong to a specific category in the create view product when selecting an category from the drop down list

Comment: call ajax on category Id dropdown.on Onchange event.it will return you json.Bind it to subcategory dropdown.

Comment: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b58fde6b-415e-454d-985b-d5dc4ad2fca8.aspx